# jQuery: get all children from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get all children from XML document and put the name into a variable = value. The script needs to be dynamic - the xml node name will be passed to the script, nothing hard coded. For example, if the user of the xml file wants to add an  node, he can pass that variable to the JavaScript, and it will reference that node in the XML file.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: xmlDoc,
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('Event').each(function() {

                }
```

What to put inside of the .find('Event') function? `$(this).children()` returns an object containing each node name under `<Event></Event>` (e.g. EventLocation), and `$(this).children().text()` returns the each value (e.g. Office Building 1).

**I would like to add a variable for each node of the xml file, equaling it's value.**

Example XML file would be:

```
<Events>
    <Event>
        <EventLocation>Office Building 1</EventLocation>
    </Event>
</Events>
```

Comment: Please add an example of the XML file you're using.

Comment: Added an example, so that you can see how it is nested.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to add a variable who's name is the tagname and the value the value of the tag. So for instance: var eventLocation = "Office Building 1"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to create a new variable who's name is the tag name and its value is the value of that tag.

I don't think this can be done except by using the eval function, which I do not think is a good idea for a [number of reasons](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/). But because you asked it... here you go:

```
$(xml).find('Event').children().each(function() {
  eval(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '="' + $(this).text() + '"');
});
```

This will create the variables for you. It is however very dirty and error prone. If the tag name contains characters that cannot be used as variable names it will crash. Also eval is slow and can be misused by hackers. Depending on what you want to do you have other options like using an associative array

Comment: That worked, but I see what you mean about using eval and defining the variable names. As soon as I reloaded the page, the page continually refreshed. I actually had a node named "Location". I already thought about making this safer by adding a prefix to each. Other suggestions?

Comment: What do you want the variables for exactly. There is bound to be a better solution than to inject new variables at runtime